# How to use special characters in SQL Server LIKE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, special-characters, sql-like

I have a table in which I want to get the strings which are like `ab aabb aaabbb ......` a n times followed by b n times as shown below.

Eg TABLE:

```
  value 
---------- 
   ab
   aabb
   aaabbb
   aaaabbbb
   1
   1a
   abababa
```

I want the result TABLE to be:

```
 value    
---------- 
ab
aabb
aaabbb
aaaabbbb
```

I've tried like this

```
select * from [NumTest] where value LIKE '[a]+[b]+'
```

but it's returning zero rows.

Can anybody help me how to use special characters in SQL Server's `LIKE` ?

Comment: What you are asking is written as `LIKE '%ab%'` but that is not going to do you much good as it will return `ababa` for example. If you want exact output you have shown much different logic is needed. Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something that can work:

(EDIT - after O/P comment, commented parts not needed)

```
--WITH CTE_GoodValues AS 
--(
    SELECT value
    FROM Table1
    WHERE LEFT(VALUE,LEN(VALUE)/2) = REPLICATE('a',LEN(VALUE)/2)
        AND RIGHT(VALUE,LEN(VALUE)/2) = REPLICATE('b',LEN(VALUE)/2)
        AND LEN(VALUE)%2=0
--)
--SELECT REPLICATE(' ', (SELECT MAX(LEN(VALUE))/2 FROM CTE_GoodValues)- LEN(VALUE)/2) + VALUE
--FROM CTE_GoodValues
```

In the CTE - select values that have left half all `a`-s and right half all `b`-s. Then find MAX length and use it to replicate needed empty spaces in front

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/50b12/6)** (after edit)

Comment: This is getting the result alright but it looks very complex to me. And I don't need any leading blanks it's just bad formatting of my question

Comment: @ILLUMINATI7590 AH, in that case, you can just use the inner SELECT from CTE